# Understanding inconsistent cythonized code behavior - PyQt5 vs. PySide2

Tags: python, pyqt5, cython, pyside2, cythonize

While cythonizing some PyQt5 code, I was encountering `TypeError: method() takes exactly 1 positional argument (2 given)`.
Strangely, replacing PyQt5 with PySide2 seems to not cause this behavior. I was hoping someone could help me understand why this is happening.
NOTE: running directly from source does not cause this problem for either PyQt5 or PySide2.

I am using Python 3.6.8, cython 0.28.5.

I created a sample application to reproduce this behavior. The folder structure is as follows:

```
root/
|- main.py
|- setup.py
|- lib/
    |- __init__.py
    |- test.py
```

`setup.py` is performing the same function as `$ cythonize -i <filename>` while allowing me to change the `compiler_directives`. The actual code can be found in the cython repo [here](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/15a8ec240d1e63c629ee1127691b0aaa2eacc738/Cython/Build/Cythonize.py).

setup.py

```py
import os
import tempfile
import shutil
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build.Dependencies import cythonize
from multiprocessing import pool

def run_distutils(args):
    base_dir, ext_modules = args
    script_args = ['build_ext', '-i']
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    temp_dir = None
    try:
        if base_dir:
            os.chdir(base_dir)
            temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp(dir=base_dir)
            script_args.extend(['--build-temp', temp_dir])
            setup(
                    script_name='setup.py',
                    script_args=script_args,
                    ext_modules=ext_modules,
                )
    finally:
        if base_dir:
            os.chdir(cwd)
            if temp_dir and os.path.isdir(temp_dir):
                shutil.rmtree(temp_dir)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ext_paths = ['lib\\test.py']
    cython_exts = cythonize(ext_paths,
                            nthreads=1,
                            compiler_directives={
                                "always_allow_keywords": True,
                            })
    try:
        process_pool = pool.Pool()
        process_pool.map_async(run_distutils, [(".", [ext]) for ext in cython_exts])
    except:
        if process_pool is not None:
            process_pool.terminate()
        raise
    finally:
        if process_pool is not None:
            process_pool.close()
            process_pool.join()
```

`main.py` is used to call the main inside `test.py` which initiates the UI.

test.py

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPushButton, QApplication

def print_arg(arg):
    print(arg)

class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.btn1 = QPushButton("Button 1", self)
        self.btn1.move(30, 50)
        self.btn2 = QPushButton("Button 2", self)
        self.btn2.move(150, 50)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)
        self.statusBar()
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 290, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Event sender')
        self.show()

    def buttonClicked(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        self.statusBar().showMessage(sender.text() + ' was pressed')
        print_arg(arg=self.sender())

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I create `.pyd` from `test.pyd` by executing `$ python setup.py` from the root directory. Once the build has completed, I move `test.py` outside of `lib/` for testing using `$ python main.py`.

When building and running `test.py` as shown above (using PyQt5), clicking on any button will cause:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lib\test.py", line 26, in lib.test.Example.buttonClicked
    def buttonClicked(self):
TypeError: buttonClicked() takes exactly 1 positional argument (2 given)
```

Replacing PyQt5 with PySide2 in `test.py`, building and then running the code, the same TypeError is not raised. This is the behavior I want to investigate.

In `setup.py`, changing the compiler directive, `always_allow_keywords` to `False`, will stop the TypeError from happening but will cause this error to be raised (this happens for both PyQt5 and PySide):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lib\test.py", line 29, in lib.test.Example.buttonClicked
    print_arg(arg=self.sender())
TypeError: print_arg() takes no keyword arguments
```

It would be great if someone could shed some light on why is the behavior different for PyQt5 and PySide2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The clicked signal is overloaded, that is, it has 2 signatures: `clicked = pyqtSignal([], [bool])` so by not indicating which signature will be used generates this type of problems. So the solution is to indicate the signature by pyqtSlot:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPushButton, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot # <--- add this line

def print_arg(arg):
    print(arg)

class Example(QMainWindow):
    # ...

    @pyqtSlot() # <--- add this line
    def buttonClicked(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        self.statusBar().showMessage(sender.text() + ' was pressed')
        print_arg(arg=self.sender())

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And in the case of PySide2, the signature is deducted, but PyQt5 expects you to clearly indicate it, otherwise it will check with all possibles cases.